# Multiple address in MailAddress constructor

Tags: c#, .net, system.net.mail, mailmessage

i was trying to add multiple to address like this.

```
MailAddress mailAddressTo = new MailAddress("sample@example.com;sample1@example.com","Vetrivelmp");
```

but throws error like

```
An invalid character was found in the mail header: ';'
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You cannot use the `MailAddress` constructor for specifying multiple receipts, but you can to use the `MailMessage` object as showed below.

Using the `MailMessage` (**not** `MailAddress`) constructor:

```
var msg = new MailMessage("from@domain.example", "to1@gmail.com, to2@gmail.com");
```

another way is:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add("me@mycompany.example,him@hiscompany.example,her@hercompany.example");
```

another way is:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add("person1@domain.example");
msg.To.Add("person2@domain.example");
msg.To.Add("person3@domain.example");
msg.To.Add("person4@domain.example");
```

Comment: what is difference bw mine and yours?

Comment: see i know this but how to set in the constructor itself?

Comment: His has a MailMessage object for a start. I've actually explained a bit of this in my answer. the simple answer is that `mail.To` is a `MailAddressCollection` that allows multiple e-mail addresses. `MailAddress` only ever holds a single address (the fact its singular may help you remember this).

Comment: yes but if i am giving format like "sample@google.com<sapce>;<sapce>sample1&google.com". it takes seconde email id and sending mail. is this correct functionality?

Comment: this will work

 new MailAddress("sample@google.com", "Vetrivelmp");

Comment: you know why this is happening?

Comment: even if there is an issue with MailAdress object you have to use the MailMessage for multiple address as MailAddress is for only one address

Comment: Would `mail.To = "me@mycompany.com;him@hiscompany.com;her@hercompany.com";` really work? `MailMessage.To` is a `MailAddressCollection` object. You can't assign a string to it - you'd need to use the `.Add` method and your list of email addresses would have to be separated by commas, not semi-colons.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso Your first code sample throws an error. The second line should read `mail.To.Add("me@mycompany.com,him@hiscompany.com,her@hercompany.com");`

Comment: @AdamMiller I think this answer addresses the question about multiple addresses in a `MailAddress` constructor better. But I agree the answer by Tscharek is more correct because it explains using semicolon as the address delimiter is wrong no matter what.

Answer (score 20):

Actually, semicolon is not a valid delimiter. Unfortunately, MSDN does not document this, had to find out this by myself.

If you want to add more addresses, divide them by comma. And the space will divide display name and email address. The "To" property accepts following formats:

- `email@server.example`
- "`email1@server1.example`, `email2@server2.example`"
- "Name `email@server.example`"
- "name `email@server1.example`, `email@server2.example`"

etc...

I wrote more about this topic [in this blog post](http://goleszympansy.blogspot.com/2012/02/multiple-addresses-in-mailmessage-to.html)

Comment: In your last example, `"name email@server1.com, email@server2.com"`, the MailMessage was interpreting a test I did as "name email" as the email prefix.  I had to do it like this: `"Adam Miller <AdamMiller@somewhere.com>"`

Comment: The delimeter is in the documentation now - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Mail_MailMessage__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_

Answer (score 7):

**Use a comma (,) as the separator instead of semicolon (;).**

> If multiple e-mail addresses separated with a semicolon character (";") are passed in the addresses parameter. a FormatException exception is raised.

- [MailAddressCollection.Add(String) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

*Examples that work*

MailAddressCollection.Add(String):

```
using (MailMessage msg = new MailMessage())
{
  ...
  msg.To.Add("sample@example.com, sample1@example.com");
  ...
}
```

MailAddressCollection.Add(MailAddress):

```
using (MailMessage msg = new MailMessage())
{
  ...
  msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("sample@example.com", "Vetrivelmp"));
  msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("sample1@example.com", "Vetrivelmp1"));
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be a question of why you are wanting to do this? Something like `MailMessage.To` is a `MailAddressCollection` whose `Add` method is overloaded to take multiple e-mail addresses in a string, separated by a comma (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695.aspx).

The usual use for MailAddress objects is to add them to e-mails and if you have multiple addresses then I assume you want to add them to one of the To, CC etc. fields in which case the Add overload should do you nicely. If there is something else then you are going to have to provide more context for what you are trying to do.

Comment: reason is i have predefined code that i am not supposed to change. so is that possible to add multiple ids inside mailaddress consturctor or not?

Comment: No, you can't. A `MailAddress` object is for a single Mail Address. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx is the docs that should hopefully answer any other questions you have on the object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation on this theme, FWIW:

```
    SenderEmail = "me@mine.example";
    RecipientEmail = "this@this.example, that@that.example, other@theother.example";
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(SenderEmail, RecipientEmail);
```

Note the commas. Further details can be found at MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14k9fb7t(v=vs.110)%60.aspx%60).

Answer (score 0):

@Tschareck

"A comma is used to separate elements in a list of mail addresses. As a result, a comma should not be used in unquoted display names in a list. The following mail addresses would be allowed" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx

Best regards,
Anarud

Answer (score -2):

This is what worked for me.

```
  MailMessage m_message = new MailMessage();
  string m_addys = "addy2@example.com,addy1@example.com";
  m_message.To.Add(m_addys);
```

Comment: That doesn't do what you think it does. That sends an email only to addy2@foo.com, and the person's name will appear as addy1@foo.com

Comment: You are right.  It should be like this:  "addy2@foo.com,addy1@foo.com".  And it is a string not a MailAddress.