# Not sends email to more than one address

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an problema to send more than one email in my web app.
If I send to just one address, it send normally!

My string list is correct, because if I paste in Outlook and send manualy, all adressess receives.

Well, it's my string listEmail have a value "caio.jesus@ex.com", I received.
If string listEmail have value "caio.jesus@ex.com; raul@ex.com; mat@ex.com;" nobody receives.

```
lstEmail.ToList();
        string listEmail = string.Join("; ", lstEmail.ToArray());

System.Net.Mail.MailMessage objEmail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        objEmail.From = new MailAddress("caio.jesus@ex.com", "BR");
        objEmail.To.Add(listEmail);
        objEmail.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
        objEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        objEmail.Subject = "System NDRSecurity - Novas Requisições.";
        objEmail.Body = "EX";
        objEmail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        objEmail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient("XXX");
        objSmtp.EnableSsl = true;
        objSmtp.Port = 25;
        objSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("caio.jesus@ex.com", "XXX");
        objSmtp.Send(objEmail);
```

Comment: Did you try without the spaces after the coma? I make the same mail as you, and I got no problems.

Comment: Did you even bother to read the documentation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736176/multiple-address-in-mailaddress-constructor

Comment: @Sachin no! No have error!

Comment: Only Outlook is known for separating with ";". Maybe System.Net.Mail follows standards and use ",".

Comment: @Zaphod If I try without spaces, I have error! an error in objEmail.To.Add(listEmail); says that not accept ";" or is an invalid character!

Comment: So look at Pilgerstorfer Franz Answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [MSDN MailAddressCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695.aspx) for solution

**Parameters**

*addresses*

*Type:* System.String

The e-mail addresses to add to the MailAddressCollection. Multiple e-mail addresses must be **separated with a comma character (",")**.

So change your code to

```
lstEmail.ToList();
string listEmail = string.Join(", ", lstEmail.ToArray());
```

and it should work!

Answer (score 1):

Your `listemail` string needs to be separated by a comma `,`, not a semicolon `;`.

Here's the MSDN article explaining the `MailAddress` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx