# sending mail to multiple recipients using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc-5 web application:-

```
string from = "info@Oursystem.com"; 
                using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, "user1@Oursystem.com"))
                {
```

currently when i try to add multiple recipients for the email as follow :-

```
string from = "info@Oursystem.com"; 
                using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, "user1@Oursystem.com;user2@Oursystem.com"))
                {
```

it will not send any emails, so can anyone advice on this please ?

Comment: _`new MailMessage(from, "user1@Oursystem.com;user2@Oursystem.com")`_ What you are trying to do is using **`from`**, how can there be **2 froms** for a single mail? Check this post to know **[how to add multiple receipients](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23484503/sending-email-to-multiple-recipients-with-mailmessage)**

Comment: According to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9736176/728795), what you are trying to do is not fully supported

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i am not trying to send email from multiple From, i want multiple Tos ??

Comment: instead of semicolon(;) try comma(,)

Comment: @JohnJohn  With the above code you're trying to send a mail from multiple froms, look at Amit's answer how to do it right

Comment: @JohnJohn - _currently when i try to add multiple recipients for the email as follow_ the code below above statement were trying to achieve what I said.. Anyways.. The link I've given shows how to add multiple receipients..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
        string from = "info@Oursystem.com"; 
        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
            mail.To.Add("user1@Oursystem.com");
            mail.To.Add("user2@Oursystem.com");
        }
```

The `new MailMessage()` constructor takes arguments for both `from` and `to`, and should be used when you have just single recipient. In case of multiple recipient, you have to add them to the `mail.To` collection

Answer (score 1):

Try ewith following namespaces.

```
string from = test@test.com;
string to = test123@testing.com;
string to1 =test1234@testing.com;

mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from);
mail.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(to));
mail.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(to1));
```

MailMessage take a single reciver for to

> public MailMessage(   MailAddress from,   MailAddress to )

Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9d2we92(v=vs.110).aspx)

So you have to add objects for others recivers in to list

Comment: so you mean i can not do this inside using statement ?

Comment: so how i can not see any using statement in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MailHandler
{

public bool SendEMail(string smtpHost ="smtp.gmail.com", int port = 587, string senderMail , string  senderPass, ArrayList mailToArr, string subject, bool isHtml, string body)
    {
        try
        {

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, port);
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;// true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderMail, senderPass);
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(senderMail);
            for (int i = 0; i < mailToArr.Count; i++)
            {
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress((string)mailToArr[i]));
            }
            mail.Subject = subject;
            //mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("MyEmailID@gmail.com"));
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

            smtpClient.Send(mail);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;

            // write exception on server log

        }

    }
}
```

//to call function

```
                ArrayList mailToArr = new ArrayList();
                mailToArr.Add("to first email address");
                mailToArr.Add("to second email address");
                mailToArr.Add("to third email address");

                MailHandler objMailhandler = new MailHandler();
                string subject = "subject";
                string body = "<h1>  Password Request </h1> " ;


                objMailhandler.SendEMail("smtp.gmail.com", 587, senderMail , senderPass,mailToArr, subject, true, body);
```